# MySQL query is suspended when executing the first time

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I create 4 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Instruction` (
  `ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CompanyWorkOrderTaskID` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `CompanyID` CHAR(4) AS (SUBSTRING(CompanyWorkOrderTaskID, 1, 4)) STORED,
  `WorkOrderID` CHAR(8) AS (SUBSTRING(CompanyWorkOrderTaskID, 5, 8)) STORED,
  `WorkOrderTaskID` CHAR(3) AS (SUBSTRING(CompanyWorkOrderTaskID, 13, 3)) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE `Company` (
  `keyCompany` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CompanyID` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NOT NULL,
  `CompanyName` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`keyCompany`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 5
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE `WorkOrder` (
  `keyWorkOrder` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `WorkOrderID` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NOT NULL,
  `WorkOrderDescription` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`keyWorkOrder`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 5
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE TABLE `WorkOrderTask` (
  `keyWorkOrderTask` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `yekWorkOrder` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  `WorkOrderTaskID` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NOT NULL,
  `WorkOrderTaskDescription` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`keyWorkOrderTask`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 5
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `AKCompanyID` ON `Company` (`CompanyID` ASC);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `AKyekCompanyWorkOrderID` ON `WorkOrder` (`yekCompany` ASC, `WorkOrderID` ASC);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `AKyekWorkOrderWorkOrderTaskID` ON `WorkOrderTask` (`yekWorkOrder` ASC, `WorkOrderTaskID` ASC);
CREATE INDEX Index1 ON Instruction (CompanyID);
CREATE INDEX Index2 ON Instruction (WorkOrderID);
CREATE INDEX Index3 ON Instruction (WorkOrderTaskID);
```

I then insert data for the tables and run the query

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM `Instruction` J
           INNER JOIN `Company`       C   ON C.`CompanyID` = J.`CompanyID`
           INNER JOIN `WorkOrder`     WO  ON WO.`yekCompany`    = C.`keyCompany` AND WO.`WorkOrderID` = J.`WorkOrderID`
           INNER JOIN `WorkOrderTask` WOT ON WOT.`yekWorkOrder` = WO.`keyWorkOrder` AND WOT.`WorkOrderTaskID` = J.`WorkOrderTaskID`
```

The query is suppended for 8 hours. If I kill the process and run again, the query completed in 15s.

I already created all indexes for joining the table. This problem occurs only when I first run the query. From the second time it is very fast.

Instruction, WorkOrder, WorkOrderTask, Company tables have 840845, 168623, 181233 and 2 rows, respectively.

I am using MySQL version 5.7.16

Comment: `CompanyWorkOrderTaskID` is stored as `utf8mb4`, yet the parts are stored as `latin1`??

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (including th eindexes) for the other tables, plus `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  (Something strange is going on.)